# Is there a 100...001 prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory

`n=101` is prime, with only 1 zero among the two ones.
How many zeros do we need to add to n in order to become prime again?
`1001` is not prime
`10001` is not prime
`100..001` ?
What is the minimum number of zeros >1 in order for this number to be prime?

Comment: There is 11 and 101, but no more primes of this form up to at least 1,000 zeros.

Comment: Yes. Not even up to 6000 zeros... but I believe there must be a known answer.

Comment: If there is, the number of zeros has to be one less than a power of two. Gerhard "Power Of Two Will Factor" Paseman, 2019.05.21.

Comment: Look up [generalized Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers).

Comment: Here is a [list](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html) showing that 11 and 101 are the only prime numbers of the form $10^p+1$ up to $p=2^{24}=16777216$.